# Loop a function over multiple datasets and multiple columns within each dataset

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a six datasets (set1 to set6), each with columns q1 to q23. I want to print columns 1 and 2 of all of the rows of each dataset if column q has a value less than a threshold value, let's say 0.1.

I am using this statement to print the rows, which works in isolation.

```
subset(set1, q1 < 0.1, select = (Column1 && Column2))
```

However, I want to write a nested for loop to loop over sets1-6 and columns 1-23 within each set.

This is the pseudocoded idea that I have, but I recognize that this is not correct R syntax. Help, please?

```
for (i in 1:6)
{
    for (j in 1:23)
    {
        subset(set[i], q[j] < 0.1, select = (Column1 && Column2))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
for (i in 1:6)
{
    for (j in 1:23)
    {
        x <- get(paste0("set",i))

        print(x[x[,paste0("q",j)]<0.1, 1:2])
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you hardcode q1- do I use y<-get(paste0("q",j)) instead?

Comment: @user2631296, no need to use `get()` for column names. The bracket subsetting does that automatically, as in `x[, q17]`.